# Is $\mathbb{R}[x^3]$ $ \subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

It satisfies every axiom to become a subset however I don't know if it contains the $0$ element or not. The set of $\mathbb{R}[x^3]$ is $1+x^3+x^6...$ so i don't see how it can contain the 0 element that is needed for it to be a subring.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}[x^3]:=\{\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^{3i} | a_i \neq 0 $ for finitely many $  a_i \in \mathbb{R} \}$
Now take $a_i=0$ for all $i \geq 0$

Comment: I think you want $1,x^3,x^6,...$ to be a basis for $\mathbb{R}[x^3]$ and then $0$ is the empty linear combination as usual.

Comment: @user289143  you've said how $a_i \neq 0$ and then said what if we take $a_i = 0$

Comment: Which *definition* are you using for $\,\Bbb R[x^3]\,$?

Comment: @LG in the definition of polynomials you take only a finite number of coefficients different from $0$. In particular you can take all the coefficients to be $0$.

Comment: @user289143 oh that makes much more sense, thanks a lot, so you could show that $ 0 \epsilon 0 + 0x^3 + 0x^6 ...$ so is therefore a member of $\mathbb{R}[x]$, thanks a lot i get it now

Answer (score 1):

Yes $0\in \Bbb R[x^3]$ just as it is in $\Bbb R[x]$.  You get to multiply any finite number of $1,x^3,x^6,\ldots $ by reals and add them up to get an element of $\Bbb R[x^3]$.  Otherwise $0$ would not be in $\Bbb R[x]$ either.

It really doesn't matter for the subset relation.  $\Bbb R[x^3]\setminus\{0\}$ is a fine subset of $\Bbb R[x]$.  It isn't a subring any more because $0$ is missing, but it is a subset.